# What is the difference between a template class and a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, terminology

What is the difference between a template class and a class template?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

This is a common point of confusion for many (including the Generic Programming page on Wikipedia, some C++ tutorials, and other answers on this page).  As far as C++ is concerned, **there is no such thing as a "template class," there is only a "class template."**  The way to read that phrase is "a template for a class," as opposed to a "function template," which is "a template for a function."  **Again: classes do not define templates, templates define classes** (and functions).  For example, this is a *template*, specifically a *class template*, but *it is **not** a class*:

```
template<typename T> class MyClassTemplate
{ 
    ...
};
```

The declaration `MyClassTemplate<int>` **is a class,** or pedantically, a class based on a template.  *There are no special properties of a class based on a template vs. a class not based on a template.*  The special properties are *of the template itself*.

The phrase "template class" means nothing, because the word "template" has no meaning as an adjective when applied to the noun "class" as far as C++ is concerned.  It implies the existence of a *class* that **is** (or defines) a *template*, which is not a concept that exists in C++.

I understand the common confusion, as it is probably based on the fact that the words appear in the order "template class" in the actual language, which is a whole other story.

Comment: +1. Sometimes it's useful for whatever reason to distinguish the "origin" of a class, in which case you can reasonably use the term "template class" -- but for the reasons you gave, it's a good idea to define carefully what you mean by this.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - see litb's answer below, but in short, the preferred term for that is "class template specialization"

Comment: @Not Sure: Well actually I find "class template specialization" slightly ambiguous, since it can also refer to the process of defining an explicit or partial specialisation for a template -- something that's not needed to produce an actual "class". :) IMHO "class template instantiation" is the clearest term.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: There is a proper term for it - "explicit class template specialization" and "partial explicit class template specialization.".  Cumbersome, but not ambiguous :)

Comment: Perhaps the confusion arises from the use of 'template' as a verb as in: templated class?

Comment: The ISO C++ wiki FAQ also makes this mistake. In https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl there is even an unsettling "note to the experts" which indicates the author knows of a difference.

Comment: @user2023370 The same page at the isocpp also says: "...template classes (instantiations of class templates)..."

Answer (score 30):

Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of C++, says in his book *The C++ Programming Language 4th edition*, 23.2.1 Defining a Template:

> There are people who make semantic distinctions between the terms *class template* and *template class*. I don't; that would be too subtle: please consider those terms interchangeable. Similarly, I consider *function template* interchangeable with *template function*.

Answer (score 18):

The difference is that the term "template class" does simply not exist in the C++ Standard. It's a term used mostly by people that think that the term "class template" is confusing (like the Qt companies Nokia and formerly Trolltech).

The Standard has no concept of it, so it's up to other peoples to make a difference. Some people use it synonymously, and others say that the term "template class" refers to an instantiated or explicitly specialized class template, which would make it equivalent to the term "class template specialization". Historyically, it had this meaning. The [Annotated Reference Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201514591) defines at page 343

> A class generated from a class template is called a template class, as is a class specifically defined with a *template-class-name* as its name

The non-terminal *template-class-name* is equivalent to the non-terminal *template-id* used in todays Standard and comes down `template-name < arguments >`.

---

To get you familiar with the today terms, which is more important than using dubious old terms

```
// (1) defines a class template
template<typename T> class A { }; 

// (2) defines a class template explicit specialization 
template<> class A<int> { };

// (3) defines a class template partial specialization
template<typename T> class A<T*> { };

// (4) explicitly instantiates A<char>. 
template class A<char>;

// (5) implicitly instantiates A<short> (because of the member declaration)
struct D { A<short> a; };
```

- The ARM called the class (2), and the classes generated by (4) and (5) a *template class*. I'm not sure whether the ARM already knew about partial specializations. But if so (3) was not called a template class, because (3) does not define a class, but defines a template.
- The current Standard calls class (2), and the ones generated by (4) and (5) *class template specializations*. And (3) is called a *partial specialization*, as opposed to an *explicit specialization*. It also sometimes calls (3) a specialization (3.2/5 - however with clarifying cross-links), although i find this isn't entirely clear to me, since it defines a "specialization" as being a "class, function or class member", which (3) doesn't satisfy.

Comment: Hehe. Yeah and several others also still contribute to that set. Notably the C++ Faq lite, and the Qt documentation. The author of the faq lite told me in a mail that he wants to put another FAQ item explaining that using the word "specialization" is better since it causes less confusion (using "explicit specialization" for the kind of specialization written by the user, then). The Qt guys told me they don't want to use the term "class template".... they find it too "unnatural". Too bad.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: The ARM was written by Bjarne Stroustrup and Margaret Ellis, roughly 1991 IIRC. Your quote from the ARM contradicts [SHH's quote from Bjarne's TCPPL 4th edition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39681575/464581). So it's good that you draw a distinction between old (pre-standard) and current terminology.

Answer (score 5):

A template class is related to the [Template Method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), while class template is just a "fill-in-the-blanks" class template.

Answer (score 2):

A class template is a template that is used to generate classes whereas a template class is a class that is produced by a template.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [N0209: Proposed Revisions to the Template Specification](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/1992/N0209.pdf):

> #### Consistent Terminology
>
> Much of the argument and disagreement to date, has been with respect to the terminology used in the chapter describing templates. Most frequent has been the varying application of **'function-template'** and **'template-function'** to express different ideas and intents. Since no consistent naming is applied, the result is confusion and argument.
>
> For the purposes of this document, as a proposal for formal adoption by the committee in discussions about templates, and for the purposes of clarifying the documentation; I propose we adopt the formalisation, that a **trailing '-template'** describes a set of types or functions described by a template. And that a **leading 'template-'**, is used to describe the template definition of part of a **'-template'**, such as a `'template-member-function'`. Thus:
>
> - **'function-template':** A set of functions described by a template, parametric on some type information provided as argument to that template.
>   For example :
>
> ```cpp
> template<class T> int nullcheck( T* pT )
> { return ( pT != 0 ); }
> ```
>
> - **'class-template':** A set of classes described by a template, parametric on some type information provided as argument to that template. For Example:
>
> ```cpp
> template<class T> class S {
>     int i;
>   public:
>     int sep_member();
>     int imm_member()
>     { return 2; }
> }
> ```
>
> - **'template-function':** This term is no longer permitted.**
> - **'template-class':** This term is not permitted.**
> - **'member-function-template':** This term is not permitted, as it describes a property not currently supported by the template definition. Using the
>   above terminology convention, this would describe a member
>   of a non-class-template, whose definition was itself a
>   template. For example:
>
> ```cpp
> class Normal { public:
>     template<class T> int foo(T*pT)
>     { return ( pT == 0 ); }
> };
> ```
>
> However, since templates are currently limited to the global scope, such a template is invalid.
>
> - **'template-static-member-function':**
> - **'template-member-function':**
> - **'template-static-member':**
> - **'template-static-data-member**
>   **'template-member':**
>   Alternative terms for the definition of a member appearing
>   separate to the 'class-template' to which it belongs. For
>   example:
>
> ```cpp
> template<class T> int S<T>::sep_member()
> { return i; }
> ```

Comment: About the `Normal` class you describe above: I wasn't aware that such a _member-function-template_ was forbidden.  It is accepted by all compilers I tried.  What am I missing?

Comment: @dan_din_pantelimon the referenced material is from 1992, so a lot of things have changed since then. For the record, [member templates are indeed allowed since C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template).

Answer (score 0):

I guess The Standard C++ Foundation is the most authoritative source on the subject:

> ...template classes (instantiations of class templates)...

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl

Answer (score -1):

Template class: A class that has generic definition or a class with parameters which is not instantiated until the information is provided by the client. It is referred to a jargon for plain templates.simply class with prefix template  and use of T .                               Class template: The individual construction of a class is specified by a class template which is almost similar the way how individual objects are constructed by using a class. It is referred to a object of the template class Ex- classname objectname(argument list)