# Need quote from standard about legality of main function as a template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, program-entry-point

On a whim, I tried to define the main function as a template function using clang 2.9:

```
template <typename T = void>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
}
```

and received the following error.

```
error: 'main' cannot be a template
int main(int argc, char **argv)
    ^
```

Does anyone know what section of the standard forbids this, and what the relevant text is?

Comment: Regardless of what the standard says, how do you expect the linker to know that `main<void>` is your entry point?

Comment: In my original post, I incorrectly stated that I was using clang 2.0, when it should have said clang 2.9.  I've since corrected that.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose - Well, I was kind of hoping that the fact that it was named `main` would be a hint.  Obviously the `<void>` is problematic, but since this is a function template, we any other case we could modify it some to use type inference so that it could be called without the explicit template goo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, how about this (3.6.1):

> A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program. [...] This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

Since templates are not functions, I don't think you have any choice in the matter. In particular, the function has to be `main`, not `main<>` as in your example; and your `main` isn't a function, but a template, precluding the existence of another function called `main`.

Comment: I dunno, the Standard does sometimes say that function template specializations are functions.  14.5.6/1 "A function template defines an unbounded set of related functions." 14.5.6.1/2 "Such specializations are distinct functions and do not violate the one definition rule."

Comment: @aschepler: no doubt, but those functions are called `main<void>` and `main<Foo>` etc, and not `main`. All templates constitute an unbounded familiy of related types, but those types are distinct from the template itself.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Yeah, I think in this situation, the fact that what I've written is a function template, not a function is important.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117755/what-is-the-difference-between-function-template-and-template-function

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm certain the reason you give *in your comment* is the right answer, but the reason in your actual answer is not!  Please edit.

Comment: @Michael Price: But either way, it would not work. The template does nothing since it's not instantiated. But if you do instantiate it, then it's an overload (except if you _accidentially_ instantiate it with `int`). So either way it's violating the standard's "shall". But even if you promise that you only plan to instantiate the template with `int` (which is somewhat absurd, why a template in the first place then?), how can the compiler be sure?

Comment: @Damon: Actually, templates themselves are part of overload resolution, not just the functions instantiated from them. During overload resolution, function templates are being considered and template argument deduction is performed (if applicable) to determine the set of viable instantiations.

Answer (score -7):

Function templates must be declared in .h file.

Comment: Even if that were true, it wouldn't answer the question.

Comment: The preprocessor knows nothing about templates.  When it gets to the lexer, all that matters is that the declaration and definition of the template must be in the same translation unit.