# C++ - Could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

I have a sample code which makes use of template programming, it runs fine on linux. But when I try to bring it to windows with visual studio 12, I got compile error about template argument deduction. Here is the fraction of code that cause the error:

```
template <int I>
class assign_array
{
public:
    template <typename U, unsigned N>
    static inline void run(improved_builtin<U, N>& a, const U b[N])
    {
        // do sth
    }
};

template <template <int> class A, int I, int E>
struct loop_iter
{
    template <typename U, typename V>
    static inline void iter(U& a, V& b)
    {
       A<I>::run(a, b); // get error here
    }
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
improved_builtin<T, N>::improved_builtin(const T v[N])
{
    loop_iter<assign_array, 0, N - 1>::iter(*this, v);
    return;
}
```

The error occurs at A::run(a, b) => assign_array<0>::run(improved_builtin &,const U [N])' : could not deduce template argument for 'const U [N]' from 'const int *'

And I have noticed something strange in the error message which is improved_builtin. In the assign_array class, the signature of the first argument should be improved_builtin. I have no idea why US appears there. Anyone has any idea about this error?

Comment: Can you post an example that would compile under linux?

Comment: @Petr, the code actually the same for linux and windows! When I called function improved_builtin(const T v[N]), it causes compile error in windows. But in linux, it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Use `std::array<T, N>` instead of the C array.

Comment: I don't have access to VS2012 at the moment, but I think that `v` will decay to a pointer, which will lose the array size. Changing `improved_builtin` and `run` to take the array by reference instead might work: `const T (&v)[N]` and `const U (&b)[N]`.

Comment: @Johny, I will try it! But do you have any idea about this error cause it kinds of weird to me.

Comment: @TartanLlama, you are rightttt! Thanks. But it will be great and more fun if someone could explain why it works in linux, but not windows? And why the template of improved_builtin<> change from <U,N> to <U,US> in error message?

Comment: I don’t think that it is difference form OS but compiler. There is MS compiler, and g++ and clang++ that I am aware of. I think that building with g++ would yiled similar result on windows.

Comment: @Bent, I just wanted to say that your code posted in the question is not complete for compilability: no `improved_builtin`declaration at least. So it is quite difficult to experiment with your code.

Comment: @LukaRahne, ya I means compiler! Actually before I got this error, I got another error which cause by compiler differences. It was explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620686/templated-recurrent-type-error

Comment: @Petr, sorry for that! Actually it is the open source project for image processing called cuimg (you can easily clone it from github). If you have time, just give it a try on both linux and windows (I means using g++ and msvc), there are some cool things happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an array in to a function it will decay to a pointer, so you will lose the size that you are trying to deduce a template argument from. Passing the array by reference will preserve the type and allow the deduction to take place:

```
static inline void run(improved_builtin<U, N>& a, const U (&b)[N])
//                                       take by reference ^
```

The reason that g++ (and clang) are able to compile your example anyway is that they use your `improved_builtin` argument to deduce the type of `U` and the value of `N` instead of the array type. For some reason VS2012 doesn't do this and tries to deduce from the array, which isn't valid because it has decayed. If you didn't have that `improved_builtin` argument, your example wouldn't compile at all.

Comment: that's what I guess too! msvc failed to deduce the argument is because it recognize the improved_builtin argument wrongly! If you notice the message error, it's supposed to be improved_builtin<U,N> instead of improved_builtin<U,US>.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as mentioned by TartanLlama and Johny in the comments. But chose TartanLlama's soltution cause it's easier to modify:

*"Changing improved_builtin and run to take the array by reference instead might work: const T (&v)[N] and const U (&b)[N]"*

This is because passing by reference help us to preserve the array size. 
But I still haven't known why it can compile and run using g++.