# How to fix C1202 error in c++ code below?

Tags: c++

I'm writing template quad matrix in C++ and want to search determinant using first row, but it generated C1202 error (C1202 recursive type or function dependency context too complex).

Don't know what compiler i use, but i compile this on windows with VS2017 community.. It will be nice if you explain me how to check it too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <MatrixNxN.h>

int main()
{
    MatrixNxN<float, 4> m1(
        { 
            3, -3, -5, 8,
            -3, 2, 4, -6,
            2, -5, -7, 5,
            -4, 3, 5, -6,
        });
    auto res = m1.GetDeterminant();
    std::system("pause");
}
```

```
template<typename _Type, size_t _Size>
_Type MatrixNxN<_Type, _Size>::GetDeterminant()
{
    if (_Size == 2)
        return operator[](0) * operator[](3) - operator[](2) * operator[](1);

    _Type result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _Size; i++)
    {
        if (i & 0)
            result += operator[](i) * GetMinor(i, 0).GetDeterminant();
        else
            result -= operator[](i) * GetMinor(i, 0).GetDeterminant();

    }
    return result;
}

template<typename _Type, size_t _Size>
MatrixNxN<_Type, _Size - 1> MatrixNxN<_Type, _Size>::GetMinor(size_t row, size_t col) const
{
    size_t index = 0;
    MatrixNxN<_Type, _Size - 1> result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _Size; i++)
    {
        if (i == col)
            continue;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < _Size; j++)
        {
            if (j == row)
                continue;
            result[index++] = GetElement(j, i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Output log:

```
1>       1>------ Build started: Project: Matricies, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(9): warning C4200: nonstandard extension used: zero-sized array in struct/union
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(9): note: This member will be ignored by a defaulted constructor or copy/move assignment operator
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,0>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(181): note: while compiling class template member function '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,1>::GetDeterminant(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,1>::GetDeterminant(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,1>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(181): note: while compiling class template member function '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,2>::GetDeterminant(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,2>::GetDeterminant(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,2>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(181): note: while compiling class template member function '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,3>::GetDeterminant(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,3>::GetDeterminant(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,3>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(181): note: while compiling class template member function '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,4>::GetDeterminant(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\src\main.cpp(14): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,4>::GetDeterminant(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\src\main.cpp(13): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<float,4>' being compiled
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(9): warning C4307: '*': integral constant overflow
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,4294967295>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(181): note: while compiling class template member function '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,0>::GetDeterminant(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,0>::GetDeterminant(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,0>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(181): note: while compiling class template member function '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,1>::GetDeterminant(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Type MatrixNxN<_Type,1>::GetDeterminant(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(17): warning C4307: '*': integral constant overflow
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(48): warning C4307: '*': integral constant overflow
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(47): note: while compiling class template member function 'MatrixNxN<_Type,4294967295>::MatrixNxN(const MatrixNxN<_Type,4294967295> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(213): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,4294967295>::MatrixNxN(const MatrixNxN<_Type,4294967295> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(199): note: while compiling class template member function 'MatrixNxN<_Type,4294967295> MatrixNxN<_Type,0>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,4294967295> MatrixNxN<_Type,0>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(199): note: while compiling class template member function 'MatrixNxN<_Type,0> MatrixNxN<_Type,1>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,0> MatrixNxN<_Type,1>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(199): note: while compiling class template member function 'MatrixNxN<_Type,1> MatrixNxN<_Type,2>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,1> MatrixNxN<_Type,2>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(199): note: while compiling class template member function 'MatrixNxN<_Type,2> MatrixNxN<_Type,3>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,2> MatrixNxN<_Type,3>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(199): note: while compiling class template member function 'MatrixNxN<_Type,3> MatrixNxN<_Type,4>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(189): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,3> MatrixNxN<_Type,4>::GetMinor(size_t,size_t) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(54): note: while compiling class template member function 'MatrixNxN<float,4>::MatrixNxN(std::initializer_list<_Type>)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\src\main.cpp(7): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<float,4>::MatrixNxN(std::initializer_list<_Type>)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(41): warning C4307: '*': integral constant overflow
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(40): note: while compiling class template member function 'MatrixNxN<_Type,4294967295>::MatrixNxN(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\headers\matrixnxn.h(201): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MatrixNxN<_Type,4294967295>::MatrixNxN(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Type=float
1>        ]
1>d:\projects\matricies\res\src\main.cpp(17): fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex
1>MatrixNxN.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "Matricies.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========


I expected this code will work correct, but something go wrong for now :C
```

Comment: Please post full error message. What is "C1202" error? What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk, description extended, thank you

Comment: You can get the text of the error message from the Output Tab of Visual Studio. That is a better and more complete format than the message that is in the Errors List.

Comment: Clearly then then the compiler you are using is Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: @Clifford thank you. Output logs added. It's a little bit hard to communicate in english for now)

Comment: You're instantiating your matrix with a size of 4294967295. It isn't surprising that the compiler deems this too complex, especially since it contains functions recursive in the size.

Comment: and the recursive instantiation of `GetDeterminant()` doesn't terminate. [How to Abuse a C++ Compiler?](https://mysticalprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/how-to-abuse-a-cpp-compiler/)

Comment: @interjay  added my main function to description. Can't understand where i instantiating matrix with size like 4294967295...

Comment: I’d be a bit scared of the copying for all the minors not being optimized away.  Also, `i&0`?

Comment: 4294967295 is -1 as an unsigned value, and it comes from the instantiation of size `_Size - 1` when `_Size` is 0.

Comment: @DavisHerring i just learning C++ and matrices. There is no goal to make it in the most optimezed way. Just want to learn something new.

Comment: Instantiation with 4294967295 is part of an answer; I think I am not experienced enough in template metaprogramming to write a good answer, I guess a solution is writing a specialization for `GetMinor` with size 2. Just checking it with `if` is not enough, but I can't explain why.

Comment: @interjay but why? I have condition if (_Size == 2) return

Comment: @PavelBelokurenko: Per the duplicate, an ordinary `if`, even with a constant expression, operates at runtime and therefore cannot terminate a template recursion (which already happened at compile time).

Comment: That condition is only checked at runtime. The instantiations happen in compile time. If your compiler supports C++17, you can change the `if` to `if constexpr` (and put the rest of the function inside `else`) which is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Don't ignore warnings, and read logs from the top, not the bottom.  You have warnings for lines between line 9 and 213 matrixnxn.h but clearly have not provided those lines.  The code you have provided is insufficient to reproduce your error.  I would bet that `matrixnxn.h(9): warning C4307: '*': integral constant overflow` at line 9 is significant here.  Also try googling the exact error message - you are unlikley to be the only person ever to have had this error:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357854/c-template-compilation-error-recursive-type-or-function-dependency

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to all who helped me to understand that issue!

All problem was in the next rows

```
if (_Size == 2)
        return operator[](0) * operator[](3) - operator[](2) * operator[](1);
```

That condition is only checked at runtime. The instantiations happen in compile time. If your compiler supports C++17, you can change the if to if constexpr (and put the rest of the function inside else) which is evaluated at compile time. (c) smart peoples from stackOverflow