# map of objects inside the class of the objects in c++

Tags: c++, class, object

how would I go about creating something like this without raising errors?

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    map<Vertex, int> connectedTo;

};
```

It will work if I am using Vertex*, but that will cause some problems later on. What am I missing, because I could not se any reason for my code not to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ template compilation error - recursive type or function dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357854/c-template-compilation-error-recursive-type-or-function-dependency)

Comment: Surely you'd want pointers to the connected objects? Not to *own* those objects yourself?

Comment: It would help if you showed us what errors you're getting. For one thing I don't see an `operator<` defined for `Vertex` so it can't be used as a key in a map.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, your way cannot work since all STL containers, including `map`, must be *complete* classes. A class is only complete after its closing brace.

Less formally, the way you defined `Vertex`, it contains multiple instances of itself. Is your purpose to represent a graph? Then possibly `unordered_map<Vertex*, int>` could be what you want. Depending on the ownership of `Vertex` objects you are planning, you might want to use a smart pointer instead of `Vertex*`: `shared_ptr<Vertex>` for a general graph, or maybe `unique_ptr<Vertex>` if your graph is a tree.