# C++ "fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex" in visual studio, but gcc compiles

Tags: c++, recursion, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019, parameter-pack

Edit2:

I rephrased the question and asked specifically, where the template recursion occurs in this question: [Why does the compiler issue a template recursion error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73008749/why-does-the-compiler-issue-a-template-recursion-error).

There, it turned out that problem is actually not related to my code, but non-conforming behavior of Microsoft Visual Studio. So, the marking as duplicate of [C++ template compilation error - recursive type or function dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357854/c-template-compilation-error-recursive-type-or-function-dependency) is actually not correct.

Edit:

It has been mentioned that the question is answered by [C++ template compilation error - recursive type or function dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357854/c-template-compilation-error-recursive-type-or-function-dependency). However, I don't see how. Possibly the same problem occurs for my code, but it is not clear to my WHY it occurs?

Original question:

I'm currently trying to deduce a std::tuple type from several std::vectors that are passed as parameters. My code works fine using gcc, but the compilation fails with Visual Studio Professional 2019 with the message "fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex".

Is this a bug of the visual studio compiler, or is it a problem with my code?
And are there any workarounds? (I'm bound to C++ 11.)

Here is the code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template <typename TT,typename Add>
auto addTupBase(TT t,std::vector<Add> a) ->decltype (std::tuple_cat(t,std::make_tuple(a[0])))
{
  return std::tuple_cat(t,std::make_tuple(a[0])) ;
}

template <typename TT,typename Add,typename... Args>
auto addTupBase(TT t,std::vector<Add> a,Args... args)-> decltype(addTupBase(addTupBase(t,a),args...))
{
  return addTupBase(addTupBase(t,a),args...);
}


template <typename T,typename... Args>
auto addTup(std::vector<T> in,Args... args) ->decltype(addTupBase(std::make_tuple(in[0]),args...))
{
  return addTupBase(std::make_tuple(in[0]),args...);
}

int main()
{
  using TupleType = decltype(addTup(std::vector<char>{2},std::vector<int>{5},std::vector<double>{32423}));
  TupleType t;
  std::get<2>(t) = 342.2;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this linked dupe is not very helpful. There it was just a typo, here looks like no condition to break the recursion, but only with microsoft toys.