# Template Class Vs Class Template

Tags: c++, class, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a template class and a class template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879535/what-is-the-difference-between-a-template-class-and-a-class-template)

i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879535/what-is-the-difference-between-a-template-class-and-a-class-template) question and i also saw the accepted answer.
then i googled a bit and found the below [here](http://technopark02.blogspot.com/2004_10_01_archive.html)

*Template Class Vs Class Template*

*Template class: A generic definition or a parameterized class not instantiated until the client provides the needed information; jargon for plain templates*

*Class template: A class template specifies how individual classes can be constructed much like the way a class specifies how individual objects can be constructed; jargon for plain classes*

Now i am confused which one is true

Comment: IMHO the accepted answer for that question is pretty clear and technically correct.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, there is no such thing as a template class. There are only class templates.

That is, literally, *templates* for creating *classes*.

`template <typename T> std::vector<T>` is not a class, for example. It is a template from which, if you supply an appropriate `T`, a class can be generated.

Of course, people often say "template class" when they mean "class template, so there's no real difference. But formally, one exists in C++, and the other does not.

Answer (score 2):

In English, the order is usually modifier-modified, so a *class
template* it a template which defines a class, where as a *template
class* is a class which is defined by a template—an instantiation
of a class template, in other words.  In the early days, some of the
literature used this distinction, but at one point, the people working
on the standard decided that it could be confusing, and decided to use
the term *instantiation* systematically where an instantiation of a
template was meant.  Thus, in the language of the standard, you will
never see "template class" (unless one slipped in accidentally).  (In a
larger context, a "template class" might refer to a class which
implements or controls some sort of "template".  In my current 
application, I have a `class Template {...};`, for example.  This has
nothing to do with C++ templates, however.)