# Calling overloading template function by func(1) and func<int>(1) leads to difference result

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading

I have two template functions:

```
template <typename T>   
void func(T a)
{ std::cout << "func(T a)" << std::endl; }


template <typename T>  
void func(int a)
{ std::cout << "func(int a)" << std::endl; }
```

And calling `func` which different method will lead to different result:

```
func(1);       // call func(T a)
func<int>(1);  // call func(int a)
```

Here is the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TjTsdzW6K). I originally thought that `func(1)` and `func<int>(1)` are identical, but it seems that I was wrong. Does compiler treat `func(1)` and `func<int>(1)` differently? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What did you expect the outcome to be?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I originally guessed the outcome will be both `func(int a)` because it is more "specialized"

Comment: `func(1)` will not choose that overload because `T` is not deducible

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `func(1)` fails to choose `void func(int a)` because of substitution failure, so it can only choose `void func(T a)`. On the other hand, `func<int>(1)` specifies `T = int`, and the `void func(int a)` is chosen because it is more "specialized". Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: You could remove `typename T` in the second template, turning it into a full specialization of the first one, to get the expected behaviour: https://godbolt.org/z/rejhPqb6b.

Comment: @rturrado Thanks for your suggestion :) but I still curious about how compiler decides to choose which function.

Comment: @Chun-YeLu the example does not define a `void func(int a)`, but it does define `template <typename T> void func(int a)` and that is a function _template_, not a _function_ (as an aside, [the colloquial "template function" is wrong and misleading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/879793/1541563)). When calling `func(1)`, `T` is failed to be deduced, so that candidate is not selected.

Comment: What’s best isn’t always obvious https://godbolt.org/z/MboWPfhnd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call `func<int>(1);` chooses the second overload because it is more specialized.

The call `func(1);` can't choose the second overload, because the second overload has a template parameter `T` which is neither given a template argument explicitly (as in `func<int>(1);`), nor can be deduced from the function parameter/argument pair (as `T` in the first overload can from the argument `1` to the `T a` parameter). If a template argument can't be deduced and isn't explicitly given, then the overload is non-viable in overload resolution. The only remaining overload is the first one, which is then chosen.

Comment: I don't see how the second overload is more specialized. To me it seems more like an ill-written program.

Comment: @ALX23z It is more specialized because `int` can be deduced against `T` (where `T` is the first overload's template parameter), but an imagined new type `A` substituted for `T` can't deduce against `int`.