# How to implement a template class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, templates, shift

I'm learning c++ at uni for a few months so I'm a beginner and in my exam I encountered a problem with template class. The task was to implement a template class in a header file like it was given in the main method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shifter.h"
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

struct string_size_less
{

  bool operator()( const std::string& lhs,
                   const std::string& rhs ) const
  {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
  }

};

const int max = 1024;

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vm;
  for( int i = 0; i < max; ++i )
  {
    vm.push_back( i );
  }
  std::string s = "Hello World!";
  std::deque<double> d;
  d.push_back( 3.45 );
  d.push_back( 7.89 );
  d.push_back( 2.12 );
  shifter<std::string, char> ssh( s );
  shifter<std::deque<double>, double> dsh( d );
  shifter<std::vector<int>, int> vsh( vm );

  vsh.shift( -3 );
  vsh.shift( 1 );
  ssh.shift( 27 );
  ssh.shift( 3 );
  dsh.shift( -10 );
}
```

The task was to implement the shifter template class in the shifter.h file. The catch was that it can take all kinds of array-like containers, like string, vector, deque, etc. And then the shift method move the items in the list by a given number, if its positive, then move to the right by 3 for example, if its negative move left the same way.
I was clueless how to write my shifter class to work like that. Any suggestions on how to start, how should the header file look like?

I tried writing the class, like we used to in class.

```
template<class T, class U>

class shifter {
T cont;
U type
public
shifter(T arr) {}
```

But honestly i absolutely got no clue how to do this.

Comment: Your C++ book should have at least an entire chapter dedicated to this.  Have you read that yet?  If t you do not have a good C++ boo, get one from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Do you know how to do this without templates? Write a `shifter` class that works on `std::vector<int>`. Then, once you have that working, replace all occurrences of `std::vector<int>` with `T` and `int` with `U`.

Comment: BTW, the proper wording is not "template class", but "[class template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/879535/395718)". It's a template. A class template.

Comment: Bond. James bond.

Comment: when you got homework and you got no clue how to tackle it you need to talk to your instructor. We can answer your question, but the actual issue is that your teacher is asking you to complete tasks without teaching you the necessary prerequisites and that wont get fixed by answers you get here

Comment: I changed "array" to "array-like container" since even with loose terminology, a `std::deque` is not an array (it is typically a collection of arrays). I think the term you are looking for is "[SequenceContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer)" but I'll leave it up to you to decide if that is more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any suggestions on how to start, how should the header file look like?

Start by making it capable of storing a reference or pointer to the container it should operate on. You probably only need *one* template parameter in your case. Here's an example where it stores a pointer to the container.

```cpp
template <class C>
class shifter {
public:
    shifter(C& c) : m_container(&c) {}

private:
    C* m_container;
};
```

Then you need to implement the `void shift(...)` member function. For shifting left or right you could use the standard algorithm [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) to which you supply three iterators: The beginning of the range, the new first element and the "one passed last" iterators.

One possible implementation of the `shift` member function:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::rotate
#include <iterator>  // std::next / std::prev

// ...

void shift(typename C::difference_type x) {              
    if(x < 0) {
        x = -x;
        x %= std::size(*m_container);
        // call std::rotate here with the proper iterators:
        // std::begin(*m_container)
        // std::next(std::begin(*m_container), x)  // the new first element
        // std::end(*m_container)

    } else if(x > 0){
        x %= std::size(*m_container);
        // call std::rotate here with the proper iterators:
        // std::begin(*m_container),
        // std::prev(std::end(*m_container), x)    // the new first element
        // std::end(*m_container)
    }
}
```

It will however not work on *all* containers in the standard library, but it'll work on most where it makes sense.

Comment: I can't really touch the main method, I just have to write the header file around it. So the two template parameter is required, because of the shifter<std::string, char> ssh( s );.
It really confused me at the exam why it should have a second template parameter. Thus the total confusion about the task by me.

Comment: @ZeleiÁdámIstván Welll, you can add a second template parameter if that's required and then just ignore it. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/r8Gaj683q)

Answer (score 1):

I got it right finally, too bad it's too late now. Thanks everybody for the help!

```
#ifndef SHIFTER_H
#define SHIFTER_H
template <class T, class U>
class shifter {
  T* container;
  U type;
public:
  shifter(T& c): container(&c) {}
  void shift(int n) {
    if(n < 0){
      n = -n;
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        type = container->front();
        for(int j = 1; j < container->size(); j++){
          container->at(j-1) = container->at(j);
        }
        container->back() = type;
      }
    } else if(n > 0){
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        type = container->back();
        for(int j = container->size() - 2; j >= 0; j--){
          container->at(j+1) = container->at(j);
        }
        container->at(0) = type;
      }
    }
  }
};
#endif
```